# How to close TIME_WAIT process?

Tags: windows, tcp, port

TCP    10.234.230.213:57273           209.95.152.72:80            TIME_WAIT             0

How can I close the process in windows?

I want to free the port 80.

Comment: Is this for the server part of that movie collaboration thingie, or is it about the client part? If it's about the client, you can safely ignore it (after half a minute or so, it will go away). If it prevents your server from re-binding, use `setsockopt` with `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIME_WAIT` is not a process, it is a state that the operating system places a connection into after it has been closed. This is done to ensure that any packets which are still in-flight are handled correctly.